# Display full width Div after selected item's flexbox row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular ui-router to navigate *pages* and flexbox as a grid type solution. I am attempting to reproduce Google Image Search Result look where the black expanding div opens *under* the selected image. I also need the route to change when the image is selected which I have working. However the div opens after all the divs in the row. Now after the row which the selected item is located. Any help on a *ng-if*, *directive* or script that could help me do this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: After thinking about it more I think I would need a script/directive that detected divs in selected's row and then inserted the ui-view div after the row.

Here what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a ng-repeat="item in professionals | filter:{cat: cat} | filter:query" 
       ui-sref="bids.item({item: item.link})"
       ui-sref-active-eq="selected">
       <div>
              ...
       </div>
     </a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

CSS makes div a flex element and wraps the square `a` divs contained.
```

Partial that opens when clicked includes:

```
<div class="expand" data-ng-if=" need something to the extent of open only below selected items row">
```